# Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush. This is likely a Vue internals bug

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, ion-slides

I am getting the following error while creating slides in Vue.js:

```
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush. This is likely a Vue internals bug. Please open an issue at https://new-issue.vuejs.org/?repo=vuejs/vue-next 
  at <Anonymous key=1 > 
  at <Anonymous pager="true" options= {initialSlide: 1, speed: 400} > 
  at <Anonymous fullscreen=true > 
  at <IonPage isInOutlet=true registerIonPage=fn<registerIonPage> > 
  at <Product Details ref=Ref< Proxy {…} > key="/products/1" isInOutlet=true  ... > 
  at <IonRouterOutlet> 
  at <IonApp> 
  at <App>
```

> **Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.**

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.
    at insert (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-dom/dist/runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:222:16)
    at mountElement (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3958:9)
    at processElement (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3899:13)
    at patch (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3819:21)
    at componentEffect (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4312:21)
    at reactiveEffect (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/reactivity/dist/reactivity.esm-bundler.js:71:24)
    at effect (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/reactivity/dist/reactivity.esm-bundler.js:46:9)
    at setupRenderEffect (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4277:89)
    at mountComponent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4235:9)
    at processComponent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4195:17)
```

If I add the slides hard coded it does not show any errors. But if I add the slides dynamically using a `v-for` loop then it shows the above errors.

I have added the slides in following way:

This is the template:

```html
  <ion-slides pager="true" :options="slideOpts">
    <ion-slide v-for="image in product.product_images" v-bind:key="image.id">
      <h1>Slide 1</h1>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
```

This is the script:

```js
export default {
  name: "Product Details",
  components: {
    IonContent,
    IonHeader,
    IonPage,
    IonTitle,
    IonToolbar,
    IonSlides,
    IonSlide,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      product: {},
    };
  },
  setup() {
    // Optional parameters to pass to the swiper instance. See http://idangero.us/swiper/api/ for valid options.
    const slideOpts = {
      initialSlide: 1,
      speed: 400,
    };
    return { slideOpts };
  },
  mounted: function () {
    fetch("http://localhost:4000/api/products/" + this.$route.params.id, {
      method: "get",
    })
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((jsonData) => {
        this.product = jsonData;
        // console.log(jsonData.product_images);
      });
  },
};
```

What am I doing wrong in the code?

Comment: Vue says it's their bug.  Maybe you should do what it says and open an issue with them.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Arguably, the error message could be improved on this one.

The error was caused by trying to iterate through a non-iterable (in your case `undefined`), using `v-for`. Specifically, before the call made in `mount()` returns, `product.product_images` is `undefined`, because you initiate `product` as empty object.

**Vue 2 style solutions**

- instantiate `product.product_image` as iterable:

```js
//...
  data: () => ({ 
    product: { product_images: [] }
  })
```

or provide an empty array as fallback in template:

```html
<ion-slide v-for="image in product.product_images || []" v-bind:key="image.id">
  <h1>Slide 1</h1>
</ion-slide>
```

or place a `v-if` on the parent of the `v-for`:

```html
<ion-slides pager="true" :options="slideOpts" v-if="product.product_images">
  ...
</ion-slides>
```

---

**Vue 3 style solution**

Make the entire `ProductDetails` component suspensibe, by giving it an `async setup` function. In the `setup` function, make the call to get the product.
Proof of concept:

```js
//...
async setup() {
  const product = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/api/products/" + 
    this.$route.params.id, {
      method: "get",
    }).then(r => r.json());
  return { product }
}
```

Now place `<product-details>` into a `<Suspense>`'s `<template #default>`, providing a fallback template (which will be rendered while `<Suspense>` resolves all the async components found in its default template):

```
<Suspense>
  <template #default>
    <product-details></product-details>
  </template>
  <template #fallback>
    Product is loading...
  </template>
</Suspense>
```

The beauty (and elegance) of using `<Suspense>` is that the parent doesn't need to know the actual condition(s) for which the markup is not yet to be rendered. It simply waits for all suspensible components to resolve.
In short, using `<Suspense>` you no longer need to hardcode the rendering logic into the template using `v-if`s and specifying the condition in clear, on the wrapper. Each async child component contains its own condition and all it announces to the parent is: i'm done. When all are done, they're rendered.

Comment: Over year later and the Suspense feature is still marked as experimental. It would be great if that would get resolved so we could use it in production apps.

Comment: This is not my problem, my question has been closed and linked to this one. Not the same related problem, just the same error, downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Also, dont forget to **await** your elements, else you can get this error also.
In my case the session store initialization function after login vue 3, pinia ;)

Comment: "await your elements"?  Do you have an example?  Might help my issue with Vite-Vue3-Pinia

Answer (score -1):

This fixed this error for me.

With error :

```
describe('App', () => {
  
  it('test 1', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Component)
    expect(wrapper.find('h2').text()).toEqual("my text")
  })

  it('test 2', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Component)
    expect(wrapper.find('h3').text()).toEqual("my othertext")
  })

})
```

Without :

```
describe('App', () => {

  const wrapper = shallowMount(Component)
  
  it('test 1', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('h2').text()).toEqual("my text")
  })

  it('test 2', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('h3').text()).toEqual("my othertext")
  })

})
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31258116)

Answer (score -9):

Also ran into this error when having malformed hooks (`created`, `mounted`, etc...). In my case, `created` was an object instead of a function.

BAD:

```
created: { /* some code */ }
```

GOOD:

```
created() { /* some code */ }
// or...
created: function() { /* some code */ }
```